# What prevents you from running an object file on its own?

Tags: assembly, linker, executable, elf, object-files

So I have been learning assembly and I understand the process of source.s -> assembler -> source.o -> linker -> executable. But I have been wondering, if there are no other object files I need to execute my program.
Why can't I just run the object file?

For example: something as simple as

```
global _start

section .text
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 0
    int 0x80
```

still requires linking even though the object file should in theory contain all the code needed to run.

Comment: If you know the format of the executable file of your platform, you can in fact create a functional executable without a linker. To do this, you have to assemble to flat binary, `-fbinary` in NASM instead of sth like `-felf64`.

Comment: Also some assemblers can make an executable without the help of the linker if everything is self-contained in a single file with a `_start`.

Comment: But when you assemble to flat binary, your assembly file will need more than your example code. It needs to contain all of the necessary executable *headers* with the correct data defined by `db`, `.byte`, or such.

Comment: @xiver77: The NASM binary output format is called `bin`, not `binary`. (It is also the default if no `-f` switch is present.)

Comment: @xiver77: a good example of using `-fbin` to emit ELF headers is https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html .  Having the assembler create ELF program headers for you (not via `db` in a flat binary) is something only FASM can do, AFAIK, assembling into an ELF executable instead of object file.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between executable and linkable format is described in [Executable and Linkable Format (ELF)](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf).

ELF file begins with a file header and its member `Elf32_Ehdr.e_type` informs the OS loader whether the file is executable (`e_type=2`) or linkable object (`e_type=1`).

Executables also require structure `Elf32_Phdr` called  *program header* which tells the OS loader where in virtual address space should each section be linked and relocated. Ordinary assemblers do not produce *program header*.